# VS Report and Sub Report Join?

Tags: report

Can you join a Report and Sub Report?

I have a Task Report that displays all the Tasks each Staff Member has to do. 
I have a Percent Complete Sub Report that shows the percentage of Tasks each Staff Member has completed.
I have 20 Staff Members.

When I run the Task Report the staff member's Percent Complete Subreport needs to display on the same page as the Rerport.

How can I make it so the Report and Sub Report are "joined" on John's name - or id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not merge them into one report?

Comment: I've tried to merge them into one, but they are reporting different information, the Report is a list of all the tasks that a staff member needs to do. The Subreport is a percentage of all the Tasks he's completed through the year. I"ll keep trying.

Comment: I think I figure it out. Thanks for helping.